# Checking whether a key in a HashMap exists in a sentence

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap that stores <city, state> pairs where city is key and
state is value. Now city names may be multiple words long, like "New Delhi". Now there are
many sentences that may or may not contain the city name. I want to check that for each of them.

One approach is go on scanning the HashMap and check for each of the key whether it is present in sentence. But if the HashMap is of millions of entries it is going to be an
very inefficient approach.

So I am looking for if there is any efficient approach to do the same. Thank you.

Comment: Wait.  Are you searching for e.g. all city names with one particular word in it, like "New" or "Delhi", or are the sentences coming from somewhere else?

Comment: Can you write your question like a unit test?  What's the input and the expected output?

Comment: why does this question deserve a +1? It's not clear at all what OP wants.

Comment: @yentup Original Poster. (The individual who asked the question)

Comment: Why don't you just try all your ideas and see what's fastest?

Comment: Is it a `Map<String, String>` or a `Map<City, State>`?

Comment: Bohemian it is HashMap<String,String> where key happens to be a name of a city and value happens to be name of  a state. For example, there is entry like <Kolkata,West Bengal> where Kolkata is name of a city and West Bengal is its corresponding state.

Comment: I am really sorry for all confusion. Forgive me. Actually the input is a set of sentences like say (a) 30 M.G. Road, New Delhi, (b) Food Restaurants at New Delhi are good (c) 12 Camac Street, Kolkata, West Bengal (d) Shops at Kolkata  etc. and there is also a HashMap as input that stores the mapping between City name and State name that I have mentioned in my earlier post. So what I want my output is that all the city name occurrences should be replaced by 'CITY'. So if the input is say, Shopping Mall at New Delhi then output should be Shopping Mall at CITY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
    TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
    map.put("Delhi", "State");
    map.put("New Delhi", "State");
    map.put("New York", "State");
    String[] a = map.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
    Set<String> found = new HashSet<>();

    Scanner s = new Scanner("First is Delhi, next is New Delhi");
    s.useDelimiter("[ .,\n\t\r]");
    String prev = "";    // previous word
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String n = s.next();
        if (!prev.isEmpty()) {
            n = prev + n;
        }
        int i = Arrays.binarySearch(a, n);
        if (i >= 0) {
            found.add(n);
            prev = "";
        } else {
            i = -i - 1;
            if (i < a.length && a[i].startsWith(n)) {
                prev = n + " ";
            } else {
                prev = "";
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(found);
```

output

```
[New Delhi, Delhi]
```

Maybe there are some bugs in it, but the idea is to use a sorted String array (cities) and Arrays.binarySearch to quickly find the insert position and check if the element (city) starts with current word.

Comment: Thank you. But I think this idea will not work when the city names are of more than two words.

Comment: I've made a fix, now it seems to accept more than 2 words, try it now

Answer (score 1):

1,split sentence to word,and split city name to word,and you can checking them by hash.

2,algorithm idea:

AC FSM,you can match many strings with a sentence with just once.

Suffix Tree,one more algo.

I think both two are similar.you can just pick one.

Comment: Thank You :) I will try to implement the Suffix Tree approach.

Comment: But if the city name appears in the middle of the sentence will the approach be helpful. If my understanding is wrong, please correct me

Comment: If the number of sentences less than 1M,the algo is too complex for the question.Choosing a simple solution is better.

Comment: Suffix tree is a good idea thanks but prefix tree will make it more simple because the i/p sentence will be parsed from left to right. Any idea of whether java provide built in support for trie data structure(example will be of great help) for implementing prefix tree. If java provides then I will create a trie for all the city names and then parse the i/p sentence to check whether the city is present in that i/p sentence or not.